# Line chart in android with different colors

Tags: android, android-layout, graph, charts, android-graphview

[image: Android line chart image]

I have done a lot of searching on this topic but still couldn't get it working.I want to make line chart in android.how can i make exactly this(in image) type of graph.I have used a chart engine library and graph view but I could not meet my requirement.

Comment: See this : http://javapapers.com/android/android-chart-using-androidplot/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use  this line for changing the colour :-

```
  XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

setting the pointing style :-

```
    r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
```

may be this link will be helpful to you :- http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Drawing-graphs-in-Android-using-aChartEngine-charting-library-%28Line-Charts%29